# AWS server timeout (OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out)

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, psycopg2, vpn

I am using VPN to connect AWS database, when I use my mobile data I can connect randomly, but when I connect with my home WiFi I get this error which I write below, any idea?

```
"OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "server.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (IP) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)"

1. I can ping the server.
2. I am using wire-guard which installed on Ubuntu 20.
3. I have checked the TCP connection, it works fine.
4. Packet drop is about 1.7% in higher case.
5. I am using python3.8
6. Private and public key were set up correctly

Comment: When you say "VPN" do you mean a corporate VPN, or some third-party service that you're using personally?

Comment: Regardless, timeouts indicate a networking issue. Something between you and the database is blocking the connection. It might be your router, or the VPN service, or a security group on the database, or improperly-configured routing tables in the VPC.